# Why does this echo values in the wrong order?

Tags: php, date-time

I'm sure there is a simple reason/answer for this: Why does

`echo 'Archive for '. the_time('Y');`

give me `2010Archive for`? I had expected it would give me 
`Archive for 2010`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As most template tags that start with `the_` this one echoes time and not returns it (which template tags that start with `get_the_` do).

First `the_time()` fires and echoes year, then its return (`null`) gets concatenated and echoed with string.

So:

```
echo 'Archive for ';
the_time('Y');
```

Or:

```
echo 'Archive for ' . get_the_time('Y');
```

Comment: Thank you! And a handy rule-of-thumb for the_function and get_the_function too, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ',' instead of '.' for concatenating strings in echo funcion.

```
echo 'Archive for ' , the_time('Y');
```