# Shortcode returns values in the wrong order

Tags: php, shortcode

I have a shortcode function that returns:

```
return '<ul class="list-pages">'. wp_list_pages( $args ) .'</ul>';
```

Of course it returns:

```
{pages}
<ul class="list-pages"></ul>
```

Instead of:

```
<ul class="list-pages">
   {pages}
</ul>
```

There is almost the same question, but for echo:

[Why does this echo values in the wrong order?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4924/why-does-this-echo-values-in-the-wrong-order)

And it works perfectly for echo, but I don't know how to use PHP line breaking with "return" (it breaks the whole code).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is b/c wp_list_pages ECHOES by default.  so it echoes before your return happens.

wherever you are defining your $args, set

'echo' => FALSE,

see
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages